# 'Drop' an object without drop using the 'over' event

Tags: dragula, ng2-dragula

i have what appears to be a non-standard use case: a kids game for which i'd like for an item to be deposited in a container as soon as the item is dragged over the container, without waiting for a drop event.

i'm thinking of subscribing to the over event:

```
dragulaService.over.subscribe((value) => {
```

and then calling the [end api](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#drakeend)

```
drake.end()
```

but i can't find it on the dragulaService object... any suggestions? thank you!